# Parsing with find and substr functions

Tags: c++, tokenize

I get a memory problem when running this code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        vector<string> tokens;
        int x,y;
        string toParse = "word,more words,an int 5,some more,this is the 5th one,thisll be 6,seven,eight,nine,tenth,extra";
        for(y=0; y<10; y++){
            cout << "in for loop " << y << endl;
            x = toParse.find(",");
            tokens[y]= toParse.substr(0,x);
            toParse = toParse.substr(x+1);
        }
        for(y=0; y<9; y++)
            cout << tokens[y] << endl;
}
```

Essentially, I just want to store the values, separated depending on the commas.

The x should be set to the position of the comma, upon which I store the information including up until the comma. I then use substr to get a new string to get bits from, taking the entire line after the comma. I get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `tokens[y]=toParse.substr(0, x)` with

`tokens.push_back(toParse.substr(0, x))`;

```
 for(y=0; y<10; y++){
        cout << "in for loop " << y << endl;
        x = toParse.find(",");
        tokens.push_back(toParse.substr(0,x));
        toParse = toParse.substr(x+1);
    }
    for(y=0; y<9; y++)
        cout << tokens[y] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `tokens[y]` without having enough items in the vector. You need to use `tokens.push_back(...)` instead, or declare the vector with ten items:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> tokens;
```

That declares the tokens vector, with the default size (0).  You are then adding items to it using the `operator[]` instead of `push_back` or `emplace_back`, so it is accessing memory that is not allocated.  You either need to size your array:

```
tokens.resize(10);
```

Or use `push_back`/`emplace_back` to do the inserts:

```
tokens.push_back(toParse.substr(0, x));
```